# vkontakte api for C#

Tags: c#, vk

I want develop a music finder program. I choose music database, vkontakte. But I can't find the vkontakte api example for c# .

Comment: Question is easy to understand: it asks for the C# API of "vkontakte" network

Comment: it is also a good question... vkontakte api with english comments is hard to find...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://github.com/grunichev/rhythmbox-vkontakte

http://silverlightvkapi.codeplex.com/

http://xternalx.com/sexy/vkontakte-c-api/

Answer (score 4):

[Vkontakte api .NET wrapper](https://github.com/nolka/vkdotnet)

Answer (score 4):

Silverlight API:

[Silverlight vkontakte API](http://silverlightvkapi.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Download VKMusic from this [website](http://vkmusic.citynov.ru/)
and use It.) It is joke. Better go to http://www.gotdotnet.ru/forums/2/127256/ Russian programers know about vk more and you don't need to use english.

Comment: I'm know turkish and bit of english. But thank you. I used google translate and it's useful.